# Animate Ember Collection on pagination

Tags: jquery, css, animation, ember.js

We are building a [ember-pagination](https://github.com/juanjardim/ember-pagination) library that would help programmers with the paginations of items in an array collection. So far we manage to put all the content, make the pagination work and also added a typeahead to help with the search, but we were wondering if there is a way to animate the items when we apply some filter or do a pagination in Ember.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Probably the simplest approach would be to create a block component from some animation library like [velocity](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity), which you'd wrap around the pagination items. Have the component take a jQuery selector which represents an individual pagination item, then just instantiate the animation plugin with the selector. You can do an `.observes('content')` and have the component rerender when the content changes. Here's a simple example:

```
App.MyAnimationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    didInsertElement: function () {
        var selector = this.get('selector');
        this.$(selector).animateLibrary({ options: 'foo' });
    },

    fireOnNewContent: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('content')

});
```

And you'd use that like so:

```
{{#my-animation selector='.item'}}
    {{#each items}}
        <div class="item">{{foo}}</div>
    {{/each}}
{{/my-animation}}
```